# Exe file does not show images in Push Buttons (Using Qt with C++)

Tags: qt, qt4

I have added Images in the Push Buttons using Qt Creator. 
When i runs it in the Microsoft Visual Studio either in Debug mode or Release Mode... It Shows the Images in the push Buttons.
But when i run exe file from the release Folder or from the debug one it does not Show those Images in push Buttons which i added in Qt Creator.

do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I think you need to verify the paths of images related to the executable and QtCreator. How do you add images to your GUI?

Comment: in Qt Creator in Push Button properties ...

Comment: Have you add the images from ressourcefile or filesystem?

Comment: What format are the images?

Comment: different ones .. jpg,bmp etc

Comment: i added from the file System but now i have fixed this Problem by first editing the resource file with resource Editor and then to Change from file System to resource file... now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Problem.

What i did is to open the source file with Qt Resource Editor .
Add the Image files which you Need to Show into your GUI.
then open .ui file with Qt creator . go to Push button Settings and then take the path from your resource not from the file.

its done.....